# minify embedded css

Tags: php, css, minify

How to minify embedded css that I get in string from a databse table? I know that i can minify it with `preg_replace`, but is it posible to minify with some minifier? With this for example([Google Minifier](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)).

Thanks.

Comment: The minifier you posted is a php based standalone css minifier and do what you want. Not sure, what you are looking for.

Comment: I would use something like wordcompress.net or a service if you are interested in WordPress minification and or cache - you can use the wordpress code for example to copy and place the function in your own code. Minfication via code functions in my experience is not a good idea as there are so many rules. 

Personally I would make my own function.

find and replace, preg_replace find and replace again.. cache..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/trunk/min/lib/Minify/CSS/Compressor.php

Method `Minify_CSS_Compressor::process()` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at https://github.com/web-developer/Resource-Handler. This is a on the fly css and js compressor and minifyer . This requires least configuration or hassle.

**[RESOURCE HANDLER](https://github.com/web-developer/Resource-Handler)**